# I don't know what to do (3 git and github errors)

Tags: git

First I tries to pull, but I got a conflict for the readme and then what ise was to create a repository a new repository, delete the old repository in git and github try to do a push with the new repository and I got this error:

```
$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enumerating objects: 81, done.
Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly36.00 KiB/s
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: _"conflict for the readme and then what ise was to create a repository a new repository, delete the old repository"_ --- _why?!?_ A conflict is not bad. Git is not SVN, this is something that's expected.

Comment: `Connection reset by peer` and `write error: Broken pipe fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` are network errors, they have nothing to do with git.

Answer (score 0):

Base on error message

> the remote end hung up unexpectedly

The problem is the **internal server error** , then the connection between your PC (client) with remote server (remote repository) is disconnected (also maybe  unstable network connection).

Keep your internet connection (maybe LAN connection, if you in intranet) strong. Try to ping to git server, for example

```
ping github.com -t
```

[image]

Comment: Actually "the remote end hung up unexpectedly" almost never means that.